# Getting exception while passing parameters and navigating to another page in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 development.

I am having a ListBox in mainpage, Once a list item is clicked, based on id of the selected item, I need to pass the id and navigate to next page,

here is my code,

```
   public void ServerList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = ServerList.SelectedItem as readqueriesObject;

  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/singlequery.xaml?selectedItem=" +current.Query_Id , UriKind.Relative));


        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        ServerList.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

   public class readqueriesObject
    {
        public string Query_Id { get; set; }
        public string Query_Status { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List<object> historyList { get; set; }
        public string Query_Type { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the exception I get,

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   PhoneApp1.DLL but was not handled in user code"

Comment: How are you populating ServerList?

Comment: Where your are getting this error ?

Comment: Im populating it from JSON response of a web service..  public void callbackwall(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string json = e.Result.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<readqueriesObject>>(json);

                //  rootobjectList results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootobjectList>(json);

                ServerList.ItemsSource = example;
              




            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ServerList_SelectionChanged` method, you obtain the current selection, cast it properly into a `readqueriesObject` and then use that object as an argument in navigation. Right after that, you set `SelectedIndex` to `-1`, which will cause a new `SelectionChanged` event to fire.

On this second method invocation, `ServerList.SelectedItem` will be `null`, as you just removed the selection, and your code will fail.

Try the following:

```
public void ServerList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var current = ServerList.SelectedItem as readqueriesObject;
    if (current != null)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/singlequery.xaml?selectedItem=" +current.Query_Id , UriKind.Relative));
        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        ServerList.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't assign selected index to -1 as it forces a call again on the selectionChanged event, which is basically the root for your exception. And, as you are navigating to another page, hence there is no need to change the selectedindex property.